# How do I pass a parameter from a static async function to another function?

Tags: node.js, function, scope

I need to pass an URL parameter from a static async function called createIPN to another static async function called QRCode to generate a QRCode image containing the URL.

I'm still new to Node.js so I have no clue about what could be the problem

```
class ipn{
 static async QRCode (req, res){
  bcrypt.gensalt(10, function(err, salt){
   bcrypt.hash(URL, salt, function (err, hash)){
    var QR= new QRCode({url})
     QR.save(function(err, code){
      if (err) return console.log(err);
       res.render('qr_page', {code})}   
)}
})
}
static async createIPN(req,res){
var URL=req.body;
...
}
}
```

The error I'm seeing is "bcrypt.hash(URL, ...) URL is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either your `URL` variable should be inside `QRcode` or you should directly pass it when calling `QRCode` function

Comment: So you're saying I should add URL to the parameters of QRCode? Something like: static async QRCode (req, res, URL)